# How to add zero in <input type="number"> after typing "dot" in input VueJS

Tags: vue.js, input, numbers

I am trying to make a custom input, where you can type only numbers and one dot. This input must return the input-value, after mathematical calculation. I am already figer it out, how to block "E,e,-,+" in my input type "number", but now I am trying to find answer how to add zero, if you type dot, because now, when you type dot after number, my mathematical calculation is not working.

````
For example(math.calc is value * 5):
if input-value "1" - return 5;
if input-value "1.0" - return 5;
if input-value "1. " - return nothing.  

Thanks for any answer. 


```<template>
<div class="token__input-wrapper">
        <input
          type="number"
          class="token__input txt"
          placeholder="0.0"
          ref="input"
          :disabled="options.isDisabled"
          :autocomplete="options.autocomplete"
          :maxlength="options.maxlength"
          :value="
            value
          "
          @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
          @keydown.enter="$emit('keydown-enter')"
          @keydown="myMethod()"
          @blur="$emit('blur')"
        />
      </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
   methods: {
      myMethod(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var invalidChars = [
          "-",
          "+",
          "e",
          "E"
        ];
        if (invalidChars.includes(e.key)) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        console.log(e)

      }
    },

  };```
````

Comment: One more think. My input work on Windows platform, but not work on MacOS.

Comment: Hi, I just searched for your `v-model.number` but couldn't find it. Did you check out the docs about [data binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number)?